# Should I heed Derek Sivers' warnings about migrating from PHP to Rails?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, comparison

As you probably know, Derek Sivers is the guy who created CD Baby and eventually sold it for some big bucks. He wrote it in PHP originally and then down the road set about rewriting it in Rails. His troubles are the stuff of legend:

[**7 reasons I switched back to PHP after 2 years on Rails**](http://www.oreillynet.com/ruby/blog/2007/09/7_reasons_i_switched_back_to_p_1.html)

That article came out in 2007 but being newly infatuated with Rails, I'm wondering whether anything has changed to make Rails more of a wise bet in the meantime, or should I stick with my good old ugly PHP girlfriend?

**Does anyone agree that Rails does not offer any significant advantages over PHP?**

Comment: This is blatently subjective and argumentative.  There's no real answer here and all that can come of it is someone saying "I agree because X!" and someone else saying "No."

Comment: Even so I'm definitely interested in this subject - I'm trying to decide whether to build in PHP, and then rebuild later on or choose one now. The answers so far look fine to me.

Comment: Perhaps you should rephrase the question as "What advantages does Rails have over PHP? (and vice versa)", since some of the differences may be much more important to you than others.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Re-writing an existing site is almost always a bad idea. It's hard to put your heart into retreading an old wheel. I worked on a rewrite of a site from CGIs to a Java app server and saw several programmers quit because of it. For one, they preferred their old way of doing things and did not want to learn Java. Secondly, I believe they did not have the enthusiasm to re-write a ton of legacy code that they had been maintaining reluctantly to begin with. Far better to try Rails out on a new task and see how it fares. At least then you are putting it on an even footing with PHP in the psychological motivation sweepstakes.

Answer (score 17):

Austin Ziegler wrote an interesting response to that article:

[On Derek Siver’s Return to PHP…](http://www.halostatue.ca/2007/09/23/on-derek-sivers-return-to-php%E2%80%A6/)

The gist of it is:

> 1. Derek chose the technology for the wrong reasons. He chose it partially
>      based on the hype of Rails, but he
>      envisioned it as a silver bullet that
>      would magically make his application
>      better just because it’s in Rails.
> 2. Rails didn’t fit Derek’s application model for CD Baby, and
>      Derek’s application model is more
>      important than the technology to be
>      used, since it represents a business
>      he understands well.
> 3. He ignored his existing experts for the new technology. Neither he nor his
>      employees knew Ruby aside, perhaps,
>      from playing around with it. This
>      wasn’t a technology that was deemed to
>      be appropriate from experience; this
>      was a technology deemed appropriate by
>      management (sorry Derek, you might
>      still be getting your hands dirty with
>      code, but you’re still management).
> 4. Derek approached the project as a whole-environment ground-up rewrite
>      with a One Big Day deployment, without
>      considering ways to phase it in over
>      time. It’s almost always possible to
>      find interface points where you can
>      replace one broken piece at a time.
>      Ultimately, this is what the Rails
>      folks wouldshould tell you anyway:
>      replace one area at a time, each with
>      a different codebase. Interface them
>      as REST-ful services. Don’t make them
>      depend on a single database schema.

Comment: Ya know what this post reminds me of?  ~5-7 years ago you got "EJB apologists" who when confronted with the weakensses of EJB claimed the "accuser" didn't understand the technology and wasn't right for those circumstances or they weren't doing things the "EJB Way".  Sound familiar?

Comment: I painfully recollect what you are referring to, as a matter of fact. So, you may have a point. But we wouldn't know that for certain unless you have something to back it up with. "Sounding familiar" is not necessarily indicative of a relationship or else the EJB problem would have been preempted.

Comment: I agree with the first comment on that post, namely the "asinine" part. It was dismissive ("sorry Derek, you're management") and irrelevant. And his points about "CDBaby didn't fit the Rails model" are unbustantiated. How did it not fit?  Is RoR not meant to be general purpose? Apologism in action.

Answer (score 11):

I have experience with PHP & Ruby + Ruby on Rails (earned money using both, but not a lot).

The Ruby library is much better. PHP's library is a collection of functions in a global namespace with inconsistent names and argument order. `strpos` vs `str_repeat`. `strpos`'s first argument is the big string and the second argument is the string to find. `explode`'s first argument is the string to split by and the second argument is the big string. This was a big problem for me. I had to look up a lot of things when using PHP, but not when using Ruby. I can remember things because they're consistent. The names of the methods make argument order clear. Another: PHP's `strlen($str)` vs `count($arr)` while in Ruby it's just `anything.length`.

Ruby the language is better than PHP. It has closures, good OO, nice syntax (this is subjective, but you need a lot less punctuation in Ruby, and that's what I get wrong most often).

That's my experience. Try both and see what works for you.

Answer (score 11):

The best answer will be the author's himself. He seems to make another comeback to RoR!:

> Foreword
>
> My former company (CD Baby) was one of
>   the first to loudly switch to Ruby on
>   Rails, and then even more loudly
>   switch back to PHP (Google me to read
>   about the drama). This book by Michael
>   Hartl came so highly recommended that
>   I had to try it, and Ruby on Rails
>   Tutorial is what I used to ***switch back
>   to Rails again***.

http://railstutorial.org/book

And skimming his own site, indeed, proves his return to RoR:

> Instead of trying to teach everyone my unique PHP framework, all
>   projects will standardize on Rails 3.

http://thoughts.pro/

The guys who changed from Rails to PHP just by following the renowned article of his, now it is your time to come back to Rails, again!

Answer (score 6):

I read that post from Derek Silvers. There is something weird about it. He tells the tale of a project that got out of control, dragged on for months, and eventually had to be abandoned. He blames this on the Rails framework. Yet he never says what it was about Rails that caused the project to fail. The article would be far more credible if he offered some solid information, but he doesn't mention even one specific place where Rails let him down. The closest he comes is to say that their "needs" (?) clashed with Rails's preferences (which ones? How?)

Meanwhile, people all over the world (including myself) are implementing complex Web applications in reasonable amounts of time using Ruby on Rails.

Given the lack of detail, or really any specific technical information at all, in Derek's piece, **it could easily be that the project failed for any number of reasons having nothing to do with Rails.**

The original question was "should I heed Derek Silvers' warnings about migrating from PHP to Rails?" My answer would be no, his "warnings" amount to a vague anecdote with zero supporting evidence. It is perfectly safe to ignore them.

Should you reimplement a PHP app in Rails? That's another question. There is no blanket answer to that one. It depends entirely on circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

Luke Crawford's [recent post about Muxtape](http://tlvx.net/post/74143734/the-technical-story-of-muxtape) offers another perspective.

> I spent my first 4 years as a web developer using PHP, and it was fun at the time, but as I began to realize how severely inefficient it was I started looking elsewhere. I’d abandoned my traditional computer science background for the web and its greater design possibilities, but because of this I knew there was a better way. PHP developers shouldn’t be ridiculed as much as they often are because, frankly, it enables people without a more rigorous background to accomplish amazingly technical things. This should satisfy nerds but usually is turned into some kind of weak ‘machismo’ thing instead. Anyways, this dissatisfaction began in late 2004 and Ruby on Rails was brand-new, stable, and addressed every limitation I’d confronted with my old homegrown PHP MVC framework. I’ve exclusively done Rails work ever since.

In any case, it would be hard to defend the categorical statement "Rails does not offer any significant advantages over PHP."

PHP is a great tool to solve certain problems. Rails is a great tool to solve certain problems.

Answer (score 3):

As both an active Rails and PHP developer (with experience going back to 2000), I strongly disagree with the statement.

I maintain that Ruby offers significant advantages over PHP, and Rails is a better framework than anything in the PHP world. A lot of this has to do with the language itself - Ruby can do things that PHP just simply cannot. Once you grok the elegance of meta-programming, a whole new level of expressiveness opens up to you.

Comment: I just disagree with this because it's so categorical in nature. You are saying that Rails is completely better than ANYTHING in the php world... That's a bit sad. Yes, rails has some great advantages, it's easy to build up simple sites, it has a lot of useful integrated features that other frameworks don't, etc. However it's also not the best solution for everything. If you have specific preexisting db schema it can be a big hassle getting it all to work.

Comment: I still stand by this comment, although to be fair I am not across all the developments in PHP frameworks since Feb 09. As someone with extensive experience in both technologies, I think Ruby has some big advantages over PHP.

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer:** I am by no means a Ruby or Rails expert.

As someone who's been in the industry for nigh on 15 years I see several warning signs that make me nervous about Ruby on Rails specifically.  I'm going to ignore the language here because a language is a language.  Ruby is a modern language with closures, exceptions, OO, etc.  Some criticize it with regards to performance.  These issues are largely irrelevant in that they don't impact real world performance (if it takes 300ms to download and display a Web page, who cares that the serverside codes takes 10, 20 or even 30ms to run?) and transitory in that they are fixed in later versions (as seems to be the case with Ruby 1.9).

**Ruby on Rails is a closed, heavyweight stack.**  I mean this as an observation not an accusation.  It is tightly integrated (including with Prototype) much like JBoss Seam in the Java world (being integrated tightly with JBoss/Hibernate and yes I know recent releases and articles have tackled the issue of using it with, say, Glassfish and another JPA provider)

This can be both a good thing and a bad thing.  J2EE, for example, being a fairly open stack was the cause for much innovation in the software industry in the last decade as almost every piece of it (notably EJB) was replaced by different projects that could be slotted together.  And of course it was, if not the birthplace for Spring, it was certainly the incubator.

On the other hand you have more closed stacks like .Net where their closed nature allows for rapid innovation, a model Microsoft has (generally) excelled at.  In a few short years DirextX went from being a joke to completely trouncing OpenGL as a games development platform because any closed system can evolve that much faster than an open standards system.  That's just how it works.

The other relevant point I'll mention is that in recent years there has been a move towards ORMs ("object-relational mapping") in Java, .Net and elsewhere and this is part of the impetus behind Rails.  I've commented on this previously, for example ["Using an ORM or plain SQL?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494816/using-an-orm-or-plain-sql/494853#494853) and I won't reiterate those points in their entirety.

As most of you would know there is a mismatch between the object and relational worlds that ORMs have sought to bridge.  In the last year or two I've dealt with this mainly through Java (JPA specifically).

Now when you bridge between two things that don't match you end up with ["leaky abstractions"](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html) (as Joel put it):

> All non-trivial abstractions, to some
>   degree, are leaky.

Now what I'll add is this: there is an inverse relationship between the complexity of the abstraction and how leaky the abstraction is.  Case in point: [ibatis](http://ibatis.apache.org/).  Ibatis is an extremely lightweight yet powerful persistence framework for Java and one I'm a huge fan of.  It wraps SQL in external files and on top of that puts many modern ORM behaviour, such as:

- Lazy-loading of relationships;
- Result mapping;
- Grouping of results to multiple levels (something **JPA can't do**); and
- Discriminated types (ie the type is determined the data).

I would estimate that ibatis has 90-95% of the functionality of Hibernate with the only complexity overhead being runtime bytecode enhancement for the lazy loading via cglib (JPA does it the same way) with the only downside that you have to write your own queries (and I don't consider that a serious downside but opnions will vary).

Compare that to a JPA provider that relies on instrumentation, load-time weaving and non-standard class loaders to implemennt that extra 5-10% functionality (and the abstraction is still leaky).

So there is a law of diminishing returns when it comes to making things less leaky.  **At some point you're better off investing in a bilge pump than you are in fixing every leak in the boat.**

Bringing this back to Rails: the leaky abstraction argument is my biggest problem with the Rails philosophy.

What also rings alarm bells for me is the comments you get in posts like [On Derek Siver’s Return to PHP…](http://www.halostatue.ca/2007/09/23/on-derek-sivers-return-to-php%E2%80%A6/)  is:

- "Derek chose the technology for the wrong reasons.": wait... isn't RoR either a general-purpose Web application framework or a pretty close facsimile?  That being the case, why can't you do a site like CDbaby in it?
- "Rails didn’t fit Derek’s application model for CD Baby": How so?
- "He ignored his existing experts for the new technology.": wait... didn't he hire an expert?
- "sorry Derek, you might still be getting your hands dirty with code, but you’re still management": I agree with the comment that this quote is "asinine" and will add that its misleading, irrelevant and arguably a strawman;
- "Derek approached the project as a whole-environment ground-up rewrite with a One Big Day deployment": arguably not advisable but if you're willing to spend the time and money on it, I don't see it as a reason why you can't do the site in RoR.

Now 5-7 years ago when EJB was hyped up you got criticisms of it based on lots of things and you'd get stalwart defenders arguing:

- "Application X didn't fit the EJB model";
- "They didn't understand how EJB works";
- "EJB is not for all applications" (they'd rather concede defeat on this one than face the more glaring issue that it's not really appropriate let alone a good idea for, well, just about anything);
- etc.

So the anti-Ruby posts (and especially their rebuttals) all sound very familiar to me.

It's worth mentioning the year old rant ["Rails is a Ghetto"](http://www.zedshaw.com/rants/rails_is_a_ghetto.html) by Zed Shaw, which is a 6000 odd word rant ("conflagration" is probably a better word) against Rails.  Some notable quotes:

> This is exactly what makes Rails a
>   ghetto. A bunch of half-trained former
>   PHP morons who never bother to sit
>   down and really learn the computer
>   science they were too good to study in
>   college.

and

> Notice how it took me a few seconds to
>   reply. This one single statement
>   basically means that we all got duped.
>   The main Rails application that DHH
>   created required restarting _400
>   times/day. That’s a production
>   application that can’t stay up for
>   more than 4 minutes on average.

and (on memory leaks):

> That’s one more reason Rails is ghetto
>   as hell. Important patches like the
>   above go largely ignored by the
>   Japanese developers, and while they
>   are very nice guys, the above just
>   smacks of amateur hour.

and

> The best part about the whole thing is
>   there’s potentially 10 new web
>   frameworks that can take on Rails.
>   Hell, Mongrel spawned or helped 5 of
>   those. My favorite of those frameworks
>   is Merb which is literally “Mongrel
>   plus Erb” but now it uses Erubis
>   mostly. What I love about Merb is that
>   it proved you could make a fast thread
>   safe Ruby web framework with all the
>   same ideas as Rails and using most of
>   the Rails gear at the same time.
>   However, the joke is that before Merb
>   the Rails Core morons would scream up
>   and down you can’t make Rails thread
>   safe. Ezra however proved them all
>   wrong by just writing a better Rails
>   than Rails and all thanks to Mongrel
>   being so easy to hack and work with.

and:

> Ruby on Rails has become full of
>   people like Koz, with Koz the most
>   senior of the wannabe smarties. Koz
>   got lucky at best and injected his
>   shitty coding into a good project,
>   messed it up, and then latched on to
>   security as the way to get more
>   control. Of course he doesn’t actually
>   know anything about secure coding
>   which is why his code seems to have
>   lots of the bugs (go check out the
>   date parsing shit. Clue: months don’t
>   always have 30 days).

And, well it goes on.

So I guess I can sum it up this way: Rails [smells bad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: I don't think that's the reason. The problem is that your arguments are either social or very general. Have you used Rails at all?

Comment: I voted you up for your effort although I disagree with you. You sound like a Java guy who doesn't like the cool new kid on the block. Yes, there are potential concerns about using an abstracted framework like Rails but it's also very facilitating to common web app crud tasks for the same reason.

Comment: Actually I deliberately avoided into getting into an argument about Rails nuts and bolts (this is the equivalent of trench warfare).  The main point is that Rails is based on a misguided principle hence it's a high level discussion.

Comment: Good cautionary advice although I think it misses the mark because, unlike EJB, Rails actually works. EJB was never more than an over-architectured monstrosity. In that sense Rails is closer to Spring while PHP is closer to EJB, using your analogy.

Comment: Downvote for basing your argument around speculation ("this sounds familiar") and a bitter man's emotionally charged invective. There have been legit articles on Rails' problems, but Zed Shaw is just a confessed troll.

Comment: "Ruby on Rails is a closed, ... stack" could not be less accurate. You mention Prototype. There is no requirement to use Prototype with Rails. Absolutely none. Personally, I've switched it out for JQuery on many Rails projects. It's effortless. Don't want Active Record? Use Data Mapper or another ORM or use raw SQL statements. There's no impediment whatsoever to doing that with Rails.

Comment: Zed Shaw's rant was from someone who had a significant axe to grind, most of it personal against individuals. And for what it's worth, I didn't notice that he migrated to PHP or Java. He went over to Python, hopefully he's happier there.

Quoting his rant is exactly why you got my downvote. It's tantamount to quoting a five year old rant from someone about how slow Java is.

Comment: downvote for just mentioning that language doesn't mean anything, as the top answer clearly shows it means a lot ... means you going each day home after work wanting to shoot yourself vs. being happy about accomplishing something in a pretty and elegant way.

Answer (score 2):

Rails is a good framework, but sometimes migrations are bad ideas.
I prefer to start from scratch, you can't be "translating" PHP code into the Rails context. It just can't be done, mostly because of the Ruby language itself and the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I'd rewrite it in Rails, but if you love PHP, go with PHP. Don't care about what other people say, do whatever suits you.

Answer (score 0):

In business, time is money - and sometimes you have to go the path of least resistance.  No environment, language, framework, etc. is perfect.  Learn and use what you want to and keep it movin' homeboys!!!!