# Is ORM (Linq, Hibernate...) really that useful?

Tags: linq, hibernate, orm

I have been playing with some LINQ ORM (LINQ directly to SQL) and I have to admit I like its expressive powers . For small utility-like apps, It also works quite fast: dropping a SQL server on some surface and you're set to linq away.

For larger apps however, the [DAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer) never was that big of an issue to me to setup, nor maintain, and more often than not, once it was set, all the programming was not happening there anyway...

My, honest - I am an ORM newbie - question : what is the big advantage of ORM over writing a decent DAL by hand?

(seems like a double, couldn't find it though)

UPDATE : OK its a double :-) I found it myself eventually :

[ORM vs Handcoded Data Access Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563775/orm-vs-handcoded-data-access-layer)

Comment: Easy to persist a complex object graph to/from database.

Comment: Easy to implement lazy-loading.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORM vs Handcoded Data Access Layer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563775/orm-vs-handcoded-data-access-layer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used JPA in a project, and at first I was extremely impressed.  Gosh it saved me all that time writing SQL!  Gradually, however, I became a bit disenchanted.

1. Difficulty defining tables without surrogate keys.  Sometimes we need tables that don't have surrogate keys.  Sometimes we want a multicolumn primary key.  TopLink had difficulties with that.
2. Forced datastructure relationships. JPA uses annotations to describe the relationship between a field and the container or referencing class.  While this may seem great at first site, what do you do when you reference the objects differently in the application?  Say for example, you need just specific objects that reference specific records based on some specific criteria (and it needs to be high-performance with no unnecessary object allocation or record retrieval). The effort to modify Entity classes will almost always exceed the effort that would have existed had you never used JPA in the first place (assuming you are at all successful getting JPA to do what you want).
3. Caching.  JPA defines the notion of caches for your objects.  It must be remembered that the database has its own cache, typically optimized around minimizing disk reads.  Now you're caching your data twice (ignoring the uncollected GC heap). How this can be an advantage is beyond me.
4. Data != Objects.  For high-performance applications, the retrieval of data from the DB must be done very efficiently.  Forcing object creation is not always a good thing.  For example, sometimes you may want arrays of primitives.  This is about 30 minutes of work for an experienced programmer working with straight JDBC.
5. Performance, debugging.
   It is much more difficult to gauge the performance of an application with complex things going on in the (sub-optimal, autogenerated) caching subsystem, further straining project resources and budgets.

Most developers don't really understand the impedence mismatch problem that has always existed when mapping objects to tables.  This fact ensures that JPA and friends will probably enjoy considerable (cough cough) success for the forseeable future.

Comment: Indeed, exactly my experiences.

Answer (score 16):

- Strong-typing
- No need to write the DAL yourself => time savings
- No need to write SQL code yourself =>
  less error-prone

Answer (score 7):

I've used Hibernate in the past to dynamically create quite complex queries. The logic involved to create the appropriate SQL would have been very time-consuming to implement, compared with the logic to build the appropriate `Criteria`. Additionally, Hibernate knew how to work with various different databases, so I didn't need to put any of that logic in our code. We had to *test* against different databases of course, and I needed to write an extension to handle "like" queries appropriately, but then it ran against SQL Server, Oracle and HSqldb (for testing) with no issues.

There's also the fact that it's more code you don't have to write, which is always a nice thing :) I can't say I've used LINQ to SQL in anything big, but where I've used it for a "quick and dirty" web-site (very small, rarely updated, little benefit from full layer abstraction) it was lovely.

Comment: Jon, tx, was it for java or dotnet? Would you recommand NHibernate over linq?

Comment: @Peter: This was in Java. I don't have much experience of ORM on .NET for production applications, to be honest.

Comment: @Jon so  thát's the field you haven't got much experience in ;-)

Comment: @amis : you have tried both than?  And you lose linq than i suppose, don't you miss it?

Comment: @Jon Yes, I was just reading about it.  Its labeled immature though, among other not nice things

Answer (score 4):

Well, for me it is a lot about not having to reinvent/recreate the wheel each time I need to implement a new domain model. It is simply a lot more efficient to use for instance nHibernate (my ORM of choice) for creating, using and maintaining the data access layer.

You don't specify exactly how you build your DAL, but for me I used to spend quite some time doing the same stuff over and over again. I used to start with the database model and work my way up from there, creating stored procedures etc. Even if I sometimes used little tools to generate parts of the setup, it was a lot of repetitive coding.

Nowadays I start with the domain. I model it in UML, and for most of the time I'm able to generate everything from that model, including the database schema. It need a few tweaks here and there, but with my current setup I get 95% of the job with the data access done in no time at all. The time I save I can use to fine tune the parts that need tuning. I seldom need to write any SQL statements.

That's my two cents. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Portability between different db vendors.

Answer (score 2):

> My, honest - i am an ORM newbie - question : what is the big advance of ORM over writing a decent DAL by hand?

Not all programmers are willing or even capable of writing "a decent DAL". Those who can't or get scared from the mere thought of it, find LINQ or any other ORM a blessing.

I personally use LINQ to manipulate collections in the code because of its expressiveness. It offers a very compact and transparent way to perform some common tasks on collections directly in code.

LINQ will stop being useful to you when you will want to create very specific and optimized queries by hand. Then you are likely to get a mixture of LINQ queries intermingled with custom stored procedures wired into it. Because of this considerations, I decided against LINQ to SQL in my current project (since I have a decent (imho) DAL layer). But I'm sure LINW will do just fine for simple sites like maybe your blog (or SO for that matter).

With LINQ/ORM there may also be a consideration of lagging for high traffic sites (since each incoming query will have to be compiled all over again). Though I have to admit I do not see any performance issues on SO.

You can also consider waiting for the Entity Framework v2. It should be more powerful than LINQ (and hopefully not that bad as v1 (according to some people)).

Comment: "Each incoming query will have to be compiled all over again" - I'd certainly hope not! A prepared statement cache should eradicate that problem.

Comment: You can also wire in SP in your linq. So that you can first create your DAL through Linq and later on optimize where needed by calling a SP.

Comment: Your compiling of queries can be optimized by so called Compiled Queries. You can statically create them so they get compiled only once. Don't know if this is what Jon is refering to, but I thought I'd just drop the term so ppl can easely google it.

Answer (score 1):

Transparent persistence - changes get saved (and cascaded) without you having to call `Save()`. At first glance this seems like a nightmare, but once you get used to working with it rather than against it, your domain code can be freed of persistence concerns almost completely. I don't know of any ORM other than Hibernate / NHibernate that does this, though there might be some...

Answer (score 1):

The best way to answer the question is to understand exactly what libraries like Hibernate are actually accomplishing on your behalf. Most of the time abstractions exist for a reason, often to make certain problems less complex, or in the case Hibernate is almost a DSL for expression certain persistance concepts in a simple terse manner.

- One can easily change the fetch strategy for collections by changing an annotation rather than writing up lots of code.
- Hibernate and Linq are proven and tested by many, there is little chance you can achieve this quality without lots of work.
- Hibernate addresses many features that would take you months and years to code.

Answer (score 1):

Also, while the JPA documentation says that composite keys are supported, it can get very (very) tricky quickly.  You can easily spend hours (days?) trying to get something quite simple working. If JPA really makes things simpler then developers should be freed from thinking too much about these details.  It doesn't, and we are left with having to understand two levels of abstraction, the ORM (JPA) and JDBC.  For my current project I'm using a very simple implementation that uses a package protected static get "constructor" that takes a ResultSet and returns an Object.  This is about 4 lines of code per class, plus one line of code for each field.  It's simple, high-performance, and quite effective, and I retain total control.  If I need to access objects differently I can add another method that reads different fields (leaving the others null, for example).  I don't require a spec that tells me "how ORMs must (!) be done".  If I require caching for that class, I can implement it precisely as required.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Linq, I found it very useful. I saves a lot of your time writing data access code. But for large applications you need more than DAL, for them you can easily extent classes created by it. Believe me, it really improves your productivity.