# What is the difference between an Spring Entity Manager and Spring Data Repository?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using JPA in a website. After exploring about options for saving data, I found 2 approach. The first approach is using an implementation of javax.persistence.EntityManager. I used LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean to instantiate an instance of EntityManager. Once I obtain an instance of an EntityManager, I can use it to save an entity. For example,

```
entityManager.merge(someEntity);
```

Another option is to use an instance of org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository. One, I obtain an instance of a CrudRepository, I can use it to save an entity. For example,

```
aCrudRepository.save(someEntity);
```

What is the difference between using an EntityManager and a CrudRepository to persist an entity into a database ? What are the benefit or disadvantage of the two approach (entity manager vs. crud repository) ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This two interfaces presents two different approaches:

- `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository` is common interface for repositories which provide CRUD operations.
- `javax.persistence.EntityManager` is associated with a persistence
  context. Spring has its own interface which extends `CrudRepository`
  called [`JpaRepository`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa/docs/dev/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) for this purposes.

I hope you know about benefits or disadvantages of persistent API. If you don't you can read answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406310/why-use-jpa-instead-of-directly-writing-sql-query-on-java-file-i-e-directly-to).

Comment: Thanks. From this answer, I take it that there is no different between saving an entity using an entity manager or a repository.

Answer (score 56):

There are several layers of working with persistent data in Java/Spring:

- JDBC
- JdbcTemplate
- JPA (contains `EntityManager`)
- Spring Data JPA (contains `Repository`)

Each abstraction shields developers from lower-level details, but it can
bring its own complexities. JdbcTemplate is a thin abstraction over plain JDBC.
`Repository` is an abstraction over `EntityManager`. It shields developers from
some complex details that are introduced with `EntityManager` and adds boilerplate code and many convenient methods.

For instance, `CrudRepository` adds the implementation of `findAll()`, which is so common that it makes sense to predefine it. Repositories have many convenience methods for generating queries from method names (convention over configuration), from the entities themselves (Query By Example). They allow to use nice typesafe Fluent API with Query DSL and or enable dynamic projections.

Comment: so you don't really need the EntityManager, if you are using, for instance, the CrudRepository

Comment: @user592748 you do if you need to do something specific that's not easily achievable with the repository methods. e.g. detaching and reattaching in a context