# Google Web Toolkit (GWT) + Google App Engine (GAE) + Detached Data Persistence

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, rpc, google-cloud-datastore, detach

I would like to develop a web-app requiring data persistence using GWT and GAE. As I understand it, my only (or at least by far the most convenient) option for data persistence is GAE's Datastore, using JDO or JPA annotated objects. I would also like to be able to send my objects back and forth client-server using GWT Remote Procedure Calls (RPC), therefore my objects must be able to "detach". However, GWT RPC serialization cannot handle detached JDO/JPA objects and it doesn't appear as though it will in the near future.

My question: what is the simplest and most direct solution to this? Being able to share the same objects client/server with server-side persistence would be extremely convenient.

**EDIT**

I should clarify that I still wish to use GWT RPC with GAE's Datastore. I am just looking for the best solution that would allow all these technologies to work together.

Comment: +1 for using a clustering web-based service for local data persistence.  :-)

Comment: Would you consider sharing your progress on this after getting answers here? (and please consider selecting the best answer)

Answer (score 7):

Try use http://gilead.sourceforge.net/

Comment: More specifically the Adapter4AppEngine http://noon.gilead.free.fr/gilead/index.php?page=adapter4appengine
  
  
Just be aware that not all of Google's JDO types will serialize. Text, Blob and User for example. You'll still need to get around this some other way.

Answer (score 5):

Ray Cromwell has a [temporary hack up](http://timepedia.blogspot.com/2009/04/google-appengine-and-gwt-now-marriage.html).  I've tried it, and it works.

It forces you to use Transient instead of Detachable entities, because GWT can't serialize a hidden Object[] used by DataNucleus;  This means that the objects you send to the client can't be inserted back into the datastore, you must retrieve the actual datastore object, and copy all the persistent fields back into it.  Ray's method uses reflection to iterate over the methods, retrieve the getBean() and setBean() methods, and apply the entity setBean() with your transient gwt object's getBean().

You should strive to use JDO, the JPA isn't much more than a wrapper class for now.  To use this hack, you must have both getter and setter methods for every persistent field, using PROPER getBean and setBean syntax for every "bean" field.  Well, ALMOST PROPER, as it assumes all getters will start with "get", when the default boolean field use is "is".

I've fixed this issue and posted a comment on Ray's blog, but it's awaiting approval and I'm not sure if he'll post it.  Basically, I implemented a @GetterPrefix(prefix=MethodPrefix.IS) annotation in the org.datanucleus package to augment his work.

In case it doesn't get posted, and this is an issue, email x_AT_aiyx_DOT_info Re: @GetterPrefix for JDO and I'll send you the fix.

Answer (score 5):

I've recently found [Objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/), which is designed to be a replacement for JDO.  Not much experience with it yet but its simpler to use than JDO, seems more lightweight, and claims to get around the need for DTOs with GWT, though I haven't tried that particular feature yet.

Answer (score 3):

Awhile ago I wrote a post [Using an ORM or plain SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494816/using-an-orm-or-plain-sql/494853#494853)

> This came up last year in a GWT
>   application I was writing. Lots of
>   translation from EclipseLink to
>   presentation objects in the service
>   implementation. If we were using
>   ibatis it would've been far simpler to
>   create the appropriate objects with
>   ibatis and then pass them all the way
>   up and down the stack. Some purists
>   might argue this is Bad™. Maybe so (in
>   theory) but I tell you what: it
>   would've led to simpler code, a
>   simpler stack and more productivity.

which basically matches your observation.

But of course that isn't an option with Google App Engine so you're pretty much stuck having a translation layer between client-side objects and your JPA entities.

JPA entities are quite rigid so they're not really appropriate for sending back and forth between the client anyway. Typically you want little bits from several entities when doing this (thus ending up with some sort of presentation-layer value object). That is your path forward.

Answer (score 3):

[Try this](http://www.resmarksystems.com/code/). It is a module for serializing GAE core types and send them to the GWT client.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using JSON. GWT has necessary API to parse & generate JSON string in the client side. You get a lot of JSON API for server side. I tried with google-gson, which is fine. It converts your JSON string to POJO model and viceversa. Hope this helps you providing a decent solution for your requirement

Answer (score 2):

Currently, I use the DTO (DataTransferObject) pattern. Not necessarily as clean and plenty more boilerplate but GAE still requires a fair amount of boilerplate at current. ;)

I have a Domain Object mapped (usually) one-to-one with a DTO. When a client needs Domain info, a DAO(DataAccessObject) coughs up a DTO representation of the Domain object and sends that across the wire. When a DTO comes back, I hand the DAO the DTO which then updates all the appropriate Domain Objects.

Not as clean as being able to pass Domain Objects directly across the wire obviously but the limitations of GAE's JDO implementation and GWT's Serialization process means this is the cleanest way for me to handle this currently.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Google's official answer for this is GWT 2.1 [RequestFactory](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html).
Given that you are using GWT and GAE, I'd suggest you stick to the official Google framework... I have a similar GWT / GAE based app and that's what I am doing.

By the way, setting up RequestFactory is a bit of pain in the ass. The current Eclipse plug-in doesn't include all the jars but I was able to find the help I needed, in Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Objectify as well, and I really like it. You still have to do some dancing around with pre/postLoad methods to translate e.g. Text to String and back.

Answer (score 0):

since GWT ultimately compiles to JavaScript, for detached persistence it would need one of a few services available. the best known are HTML5 stores and Gears (both use SQLite!).  of course, neither is widely deployed, so you'd have to convince your users to either use a modern browser or install a little-known plugin.  be sure to degrade to a usable subset if the user doesn't comply

Comment: By detached they are talking about sending hibernate etc enhanced dtos not persistance in the browser.

Comment: typical case of terms collision.

Answer (score 0):

What about directly using [Datastore API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/package-summary.html) to load/store POJO domain objects?

It should be comparable to DTO approach, meaning e.g. that you have to manually handle all fields (if you don't use tricks like reflection-based automation) while it should give you more flexibility and full access to all Datastore features.