# GWT and Key object

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I'm writing Java app using GWT on Google AppEngine. So I have JDO Entities on Server side and POJO DTOs on Client's side. For some of my entities I have to use Key objects for ids Pojo's cannot have that object because that is not standard class. is there any easy work around for this so I can use Key object on server side and String or Long on client's side.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, it is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988217/gwt-with-jdo-problem

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Key class in GWT code by adding these additional jar files:

http://www.resmarksystems.com/code/

- appengine-utils-client-1.0.jar
- appengine-utils-server-1.0.jar

This basically gives the GWT compiler a GWT-friendly version of the Key and other AppEngine classes. (like Text, Blob and User..)

To use:

- Add the appengine-utils-client-1.0.jar anywhere in your build path.
- Put the appengine-utils-server-1.0.jar to your WEB-INF/lib folder.

In your GWT module add the following:

```
<inherits name="com.resmarksystems.AppEngineDataTypes"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is a duplicate, like the comment says, but I'll add another thing for you to think about. I'm trying out [Objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/) now and I think its fantastic (and its fully operable with GWT without DTOs.) Take a look at it.