# dynamic vs var in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the difference between dynamic(C# 4) and var?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961581/whats-the-difference-between-dynamicc-4-and-var)

What is the difference between dynamic and var keyword in .NET 4.0 (VS 2010). As per MSDN, the definition of dynamic is - *Dynamic lookup allows you to write method, operator and indexer calls, property and field accesses, and even object invocations which bypass the normal static binding of C# and instead gets resolved dynamically*.

Whereas the definition for var is - *An implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type yourself, but the compiler determines the type*.

How is this different in the code context below:

```
var a1 = new A();
a1.Foo(1);

dynamic a2 = new A();
a2.Foo(1);
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961581/whats-the-difference-between-dynamicc-4-and-var

Answer (score 92, accepted):

`var` means the *static* type is inferred - in your case it's exactly equivalent to

```
A a1 = new A();
```

All the binding is still done *entirely* statically. If you look at the generated code, it will be exactly the same as with the above declaration.

`dynamic` means that all any expression using `a2` is bound at execution time rather than at compile-time, so it can behave dynamically. The compiler won't check whether the `Foo` method exists - the behaviour is determined at execution time. Indeed, if the object implements `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` it could decide what to do with the call at execution time, responding to *any* method call (or other kind of use) - in other words, there doesn't have to be a "real" method called `Foo` at all.

If you look at the generated code in the dynamic situation, you'll find all kinds of weird and wonderful stuff going on to do with call sites and binders.

Answer (score 24):

`var` is type safe, in that it uses type inference.
Writing `var a = new A();` is a shorthand for `A a = new A();`.
A variable which is declared `dynamic` is NOT type safe and the compiler does nothing to check that the methods you call on it exist.

Answer (score 13):

In the `var` case, A() has to have a `.Foo(int)` method on it during compilation.

In the `dynamic` case, it doesn't.