# what is Dotnet Module, dynamic keyword and 

Tags: .net

Last day I have been interviewed and the interviewer asked me

a) what is dotnet Modules?

b) What is the new dynamic keyword and what is it's use(dot net 4.0)

c) what is the difference between dynamic keyword and var(dotnet 3.5+)

d) What is the difference between Var & Object? Why should we use one over another?

Could anyone be kind enough in answering this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Module Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aaxss7da(VS.71).aspx)

> Modules are a reference type similar
>   to classes, but with some important
>   distinctions. The members of a module
>   are implicitly Shared and scoped to
>   the declaration space of the standard
>   module's containing namespace, rather
>   than just to the module itself. Unlike
>   classes, modules can never be
>   instantiated, do not support
>   inheritance, and cannot implement
>   interfaces. A module can only be
>   declared in a namespace and cannot be
>   nested in another type.

From [dynamic (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741(VS.100).aspx)

> The dynamic type enables the
>   operations in which it occurs to
>   bypass compile-time type checking.
>   Instead, these operations are resolved
>   at run time. The type simplifies
>   access to COM APIs such as the Office
>   Automation APIs, and also to dynamic
>   APIs such as IronPython libraries, and
>   to the HTML Document Object Model
>   (DOM).

And [[c#] dynamic vs var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920790/c-dynamic-vs-var)

Comment: Hi Astender, Thanks fo rthe asnwer. But what is the real benefit of modules? How can we use it and in what scenario?.Thanks in adv

Comment: This should explain it a little better http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/net/nets9p7.html

Comment: Is it a vb.net feature and not C#?