# Deserialize JSON using Newtonsoft and biding View (MVVM)

Tags: c#, json, mvvm, xamarin.forms, json.net

I'm a beginner in C # and Xamarin. I'm trying to deserialize json arrays with newtonsoft?
Here is my json file:

```js
{
    "next": {
        "$ref": "http://192.168.0.100:8080/ords/hr/employees/?page=1"
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "empno": 7369,
            "ename": "SMITH",
            "job": "CLERK",
            "mgr": 7902,
            "sal": 800,
            "deptno": 20
        },
        {
            "empno": 7934,
            "ename": "MILLER",
            "job": "CLERK",
            "mgr": 7782,
            "sal": 1300,
            "deptno": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

Her is my model class:

```js
public class RootObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("items")]
        public Item[] Items { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("next")]
        public Next Next { get; set; }
    }

    public class Next
    {
        [JsonProperty("$ref")]
        public string Ref { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        [JsonProperty("deptno")]
        public long Deptno { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("empno")]
        public long Empno { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ename")]
        public string Ename { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("job")]
        public string Job { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("mgr")]
        public long Mgr { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sal")]
        public long Sal { get; set; }
    }
```

When I try deserialize into a List it throws exception on this line:

```js
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
```

The error is:

> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

**This code desirialize the Json, but I don't now retrive the data and populate the class:**

```js
public class ApiServices    {


        public async Task<RootObject> GetRootObject()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var url = string.Format("http://mysite/ords/hr/employees");
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

           dynamic jsonDe = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

            return jsonDe;
        }
```

I have already created some code in MainViewModel, but I do not know how to retrieve the data and insert the class Item:

```js
public class MainViewModel
    {
        #region Properties
     
        public ObservableCollection<RootItemViewModel> RootObjects { get; set; }

        private ApiServices apiServices;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            //Create observable collections
            RootObjects = new ObservableCollection<RootItemViewModel>();

            //Instance services
            apiServices = new ApiServices();

            //Load Data
            LoadData();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods


        private async void LoadData()

        {
            var emps = new RootObject();
                      
            emps = await apiServices.GetRootObject();

            RootObjects.Clear();

            foreach (var item in RootObjects)
            {

                RootObjects.Add(new RootItemViewModel
                {


                });
            }
        }
            
        #endregion
    }
}
```

The class RootItemViewModel:

```js
    public class RootItemViewModel : RootObject
    {

       
    }
```

Comment: try JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json); your json top level is an object not a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Your Json response shows, that it just holds an instance of the type `RootObject`.

**2)** `var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);` **will not** work therefore, because you try to cast a `RootObject` to a `List<RootObject>`. Described in your error response.

**3)** `dynamic jsonDe = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);` will work because here you cast a `RootObject` to a `RootObject`. I also suggest you tu use "var" instead of "dynamic" (see why: [dynamic vs var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920790/dynamic-vs-var#1920822))

**4)** your following method seems to have a mistake in there:

```
private async void LoadData()
{
    var emps = new RootObject();

    emps = await apiServices.GetRootObject();

    RootObjects.Clear();

    //Mistake:
    //You iterate through the previously cleared observable collection.
    //it really should be "foreach (var item in emps.Items)"
    foreach (var item in RootObjects)
    {

        RootObjects.Add(new RootItemViewModel
        {


        });
    }
}
```

**5)** It looks like you wanted to feed the observable collection with the array of type `Item` on your `RootObject`:

```
public class RootObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("items")]
        public Item[] Items { get; set; } //This property

        [JsonProperty("next")]
        public Next Next { get; set; }
    }
```

So what you actually should be doing is setting the data like this:

```
private async void GetRootObjectItems()
        {
            RootObject emps = await apiServices.GetRootObject();   //Get the root object
            RootObjects.Clear();                        //clear the list

            foreach (var item in emps.Items)    //Important, to get the data from the Array on the RootObject
            {
                ///its a nice way to give your viewmodel a ctor signature that ensures a correct initialization
                ///public RootItemViewModel(Item item)
                ///{ 
                /// this.Deptno = item.Deptno;
                ///}
                RootObjects.Add(new RootItemViewModel(item));  
            }
        }
    }
```

**6)** It makes no sense for your `RootItemViewModel` to inherit from `RootObject`. You should make it inherit from `Item` or have it hold a property of type `Item`.

I hope I could clear things up!

Comment: Great example! thank you. The code worked! and my view is binding to the viewmodel

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you too

Comment: please can you explain better... This part `RootObjects.Add(new RootItemViewModel(item));`   in my code is showing error that **RootItemViewModel does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments**

Comment: So sorry to disturb. I realized my viewModel was pointing to another collection fro the start. I've solved the issue

Comment: So sorry to disturb. I realized my viewModel was pointing to another collection fro the start. I've solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

For this JSON:

```
{
"next": {
    "$ref": "http://192.168.0.100:8080/ords/hr/employees/?page=1"
},
"items": [
    {
        "empno": 7369,
        "ename": "SMITH",
        "job": "CLERK",
        "mgr": 7902,
        "sal": 800,
        "deptno": 20
    },
    {
        "empno": 7934,
        "ename": "MILLER",
        "job": "CLERK",
        "mgr": 7782,
        "sal": 1300,
        "deptno": 10
    }
]
```

}

Use this Class:

```
internal class SomeObject{ //in C# you can even NOT to define internal as well :)
public class next{
    public string ref {get; set;} //var do not use $, you need to change the JSON code or you nned to make a custom reader for that.
}

public List<Item> items {get; set;}

public class Item{
    public string empno {get; set;}
    public string ename {get; set;}
    public string job {get; set;}
    public string mgr {get; set;}
    public string sal {get; set;}
    public string deptno {get; set;}
}
}
```

To deserialize those JSON to a Class, use this one:

```
    var obj = JSONConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeObject>(json); //json is a string of your JSON

//Now you can access the data like 

listView.ItemsSource = obj.Items; //for mobile listview
```

You cannot put List because the JSON object is not pure List Of object, it is combined object between next object and items object. So you need to create a class first before putting the JSON into list.

Answer (score 0):

http://json2csharp.com/ is always useful, ( quick way to get the class 'skeleton' )

like 'Mr Hery' wrote you might have to do a custom reader or remove the $ sign - if you are generating the json output yourself.

```
public class Next
{
    public string @ref { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int empno { get; set; }
    public string ename { get; set; }
    public string job { get; set; }
    public int mgr { get; set; }
    public int sal { get; set; }
    public int deptno { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject //(rename class you something better like Employees)
{
    public Next next { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}
```

For Deserializing :

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

or

```
var _employees = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employees>(json);
```

Comment: Thanks @bomanden. The object "next" is automatically generated by Oracle to handle pagination.