# What is difference between static and dynamic variables in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Could you some one explain me detailed difference between static type and dynamic variables in C#?

static i mean is (static type) general variable.
And also how dymanic variable is different from var and object?

Comment: You mean with and without the `dynamic` keyword, or the difference between the `static` and `dynamic` keywords?

Comment: @chibacity: Oh, think of all the possibilities we could come up with.

Comment: Can anyone tell me the common ground between them?

Comment: Seems he about 'var' keyword.. Right?

Comment: Do you mean instance variables?

Comment: I'd tell you "static variables are shared amongst all instances of a class and dynamic variables are late-bound" but somehow I doubt that's the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Probably means this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961581/whats-the-difference-between-dynamicc-4-and-var

Comment: @Veeru Please see the comments (and links) and edit the question with more details. I believe there is a valid question here, but it needs to be written more clearly.

Comment: static i mean is (static type) general variable. And also how dymanic variable is different from var and object?

Comment: @Veeru You original question was not very clear at all. Unfortunately you asked the question and then left it for 1 hour before handling any comments. In that time your question was closed. It will now take 5 votes to re-open it, which is very unlikely. The question is still unclear. Perhaps you should ask a series of smaller more well-defined questions?

Answer (score 3):

In this video talk, Anders Hejlsberg, does a great job in explaining what the `dynamic` variables are in the new C# 4.0.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/matthijs/C-40-and-beyond-by-Anders-Hejlsberg
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic variables are seen as type `Object` in your source code and any members that you access from them are bound at run time. Static variables have their types known at compile-time, and hence member accesses are directly placed into the assembly at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic variable is a variable whose address is determined when the program is run.A static variable has memory reserved for it at compilation time.

In terms of ASP.Net the Static variable is equalent to the Application variable.

Answer (score 0):

The type of a `dynamic` variable is resolved at run-time.