# Declare a variable using a Type variable

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have this code:

```
Type leftType = workItem[LeftFieldName].GetType();
```

I then want to declare a variable of that type:

```
leftType someVar;
```

Is that possible?

Comment: No, you don't.  Think carefully about it, and you'll realize that such a variable would be utterly useless.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? There's possibly another way to solve your actual problem.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do something like these and cast them to a known interface.

```
var someVar = Convert.ChangeType(someOriginalValue, workItem[LeftFieldName].GetType());
var someVar = Activator.CreateInstance(workItem[LeftFieldName].GetType());
```

If you replace `var` with `dynamic` (and you are using .Net 4), you can call the methods you *expect* on the someVar object.  If they don't exist, you'll just get a MissingMethodException.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed.

Comment: It seems a bit of a work. Is it the best way to do things !? There isn't another (better) way to create variables of dynamic types ?

Comment: @MoheTheDreamy Despite the fact that this is the **easiest way** for creating variables is: `var someVar = workItem[LeftFieldName]`, nevertheless **it's not safe**, because you can accidentally **alter** (in case of a *reference type*) **value** of the original object. I'd recommend you to stick with the strategy described in the [Austin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800446/declare-a-variable-using-a-type-variable/4800501#4800501)'s answer (`var someVar = Activator.CreateInstance(workItem[LeftFieldName].GetType());`)

Comment: Activator.CreateInstance does not work if there is no parameterless constructor for the type e.g. "string"

Answer (score 12):

This is not possible.

Variable types are a compile-time concept; it would make no sense to declare a variable of a type *which is not known until runtime*.
You wouldn't be able to do anything with the variable, since you wouldn't know what type it is.

You're probably looking for the `dynamic` keyword.

Comment: A possible use case: In my MVC project I have a `Form` object and I add the fields I want to edit using something like `new EditField<MemberAddress>(e => e.AddressId)`. I use the `MemberExpression` to create the right form element, but some types need a default value. EG `long` has default 0 and `DateTime` has a date as default. Instead of creating a lot of If statements to set the proper default value for every type, I simple create an Instance like Austin explained and use `.ToString()` to get the right default value.

Answer (score 4):

No, that is not possible. The type of a variable has to be known at compile time.

You can declare a variable of type `object`, it will be capable of storing any data type.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that.

You could use the [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) type for .Net 4, but for earlier .Net versions, the only type that will fit is `object`, which you will need to manually cast later by again testing `.GetType()` on what you assigned to the `object`-typed variable.

Reading: [SO link: whats-the-difference-between-dynamicc-4-and-var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961581/whats-the-difference-between-dynamicc-4-and-var)

Comment: Not sure how this applies.  The use of 'var' doesn't matter here.

Comment: You may notice I changed `var someVar;` to `var someVar = ` which assigns it then to implicitly type `someVar`.  This gets around typing `someVar` specifically which is what the OP was after. Like not having to figure out a db column type.

Comment: i hope you know that *var* ALWAYS will be resolved to a specific type at compile time!

Answer (score 3):

object x = Activator.CreateInstance(Type) will let you create the object.  Whether you can do much with it beyond that point, I'm not sure.

Comment: That will create an instance of that type, not a variable of that type.

Answer (score 2):

`GetType` is evaluated at run-time, and non-`dynamic` declaration is at compile-time (it does get more specific than that, yes), so no. Even `var` will require you to assign a value to it that is of unambiguous type.