# What is the practical difference between dynamic and T in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, generics, dynamic

I read about Type `dynamic` in C# 2010. (the corresponding [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264736.aspx) entry)

I am confused about the practical difference between `T` and `dynamic` while developing generic functions. My current tests didn't show new ways to use `dynamic`a way, that isn't possible with `T`. In addition it seems, that dynamic needs much more time in runtime to achieve the same tasks.

Some example code to make my point clear:

```
// Sample Object
public class SampleObj
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

My Test-Method (*measuring speed as well*):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sampleObj1 = new SampleObj { Test = "Test1" };
    var sampleObj2 = new SampleObj { Test = "Test2" };

    Stopwatch c1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    bool res1 = CompareObjectsT<SampleObj>(sampleObj1, sampleObj2);
    c1.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Comparison T: {0} time: {1} ms", res1, c1.ElapsedMilliseconds);


    Stopwatch c2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    bool res2 = CompareObjectsDyna(sampleObj1, sampleObj2);
    Console.WriteLine("Comparison dynamic: {0} time: {1} ms", res2, c2.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    c2.Stop();

    var instance = new X<SampleObj>();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The result is:

```
Comparison T: False time: 6 ms
Comparison dynamic: False time: 3969 ms
```

The dynamic functions needs **much** more time, compared to the T comparison.

Decompiling my test application reveals heavy usage of reflection which may lead to this huge amount of time:

```
private static bool CompareObjectsDyna([Dynamic] object source1, [Dynamic] object source2)
{
    if (<CompareObjectsDyna>o__SiteContainer2.<>p__Site3 == null)
    {
        <CompareObjectsDyna>o__SiteContainer2.<>p__Site3 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, bool>>.Create(Binder.Convert(CSharpBinderFlags.None, typeof(bool), typeof(Program)));
    }
    if (<CompareObjectsDyna>o__SiteContainer2.<>p__Site4 == null)
    {
        <CompareObjectsDyna>o__SiteContainer2.<>p__Site4 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object>>.Create(Binder.InvokeMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None, "Equals", null, typeof(Program), new CSharpArgumentInfo[] { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.IsStaticType | CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.UseCompileTimeType, null), CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null), CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null) }));
    }
    return <CompareObjectsDyna>o__SiteContainer2.<>p__Site3.Target(<CompareObjectsDyna>o__SiteContainer2.<>p__Site3, <CompareObjectsDyna>o__SiteContainer2.<>p__Site4.Target(<CompareObjectsDyna>o__SiteContainer2.<>p__Site4, typeof(object), source1, source2));
}
```

I considered [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961581/whats-the-difference-between-dynamicc-4-and-var) but this hasn't ansered my question.

Can someone tell me, in what scenario dynamic is much more effective than T?
(*hopefully with a small practical sample*)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer is that generic type T must be known at compile time, but dynamic is inferred at runtime.