# Can't use variables of type "Type" to convert objects

Tags: c#, typeof, activator, gettype

This question will seem similar to some that have been asked before, but bear with me.

Basically, I want to instantiate a variable at runtime using nothing but a string that represents the type the variable needs to be. Pretty much every existing question gave me something like this:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(stringrepresentingType);
var newObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

This works, but as it stands, `newObject` is type `object`. I want to be able to convert the object created by the Activator into the type stored in `type`, so it would look like this:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(stringRepresentingType);
var newObject = (type)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

This throws errors due to `type` being a variable. I've also tried `typeof(type)` and `(Type.GetType(stringRepresentingType)` before the Activator, and neither work.

How can I convert the `newObject` variable without using an if/else?

Edit:
I'll be using `newObject` in logical comparisons (such as == or ||), hence the reason I can't leave it as type `object`. I know I can just use an if/else to check the type after the fact, but I was curious if there was a more elegant solution. I'd use `dynamic` as opposed to `var`, but unfortunately Unity3D does not support it.

Comment: Generics are your friend.

Comment: @Rob, Generics will not help here -because type known only in runtime.

Comment: @Fabio Good catch, I missed the string being used to create the type.

Comment: @GReusch Since you don't know the type at compile time, there's no use in casting it to anything except object. Any intellisense/type checking provided will be useless - since it could be *anything* at runtime.

Comment: `newObject` is already the instance of type you want. Can you show how you use it and why you need to cast it?

Comment: Maybe go with dynamic keyword, because this is made for something like this. But not sure if this bring you any advantage in your case.

Comment: GReusch, Please read [var vs. dynamic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961581/whats-the-difference-between-dynamicc-4-and-var) carefully. If that post does not help - make sure to [edit] your question with explanation how you plan to use your `newObject` strongly typed value.

Comment: Try checking `if(newObject is YourType)` which should return true I believe, you would have to manually cast it to let compiler know on compile time