# Adding references in NETStandard class library

Tags: c#, .net-standard

I'm trying to get my head around the NETStandard class libraries, for a potential NuGet package I'm working on. This is the very first time I'm playing around with NuGet and NETStandard packages however, so I'm a bit lost on some points, one of these being referencing system libraries.

The `dynamic` type is part of `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute`, however, a reference to said DLL is not present. I though that I'd just go ahead and add it, but I can't seem to do so. I suppose this doesn't work like a framework class library?

If I right-click on my `Dependencies` folder in my solution explorer, and click on `Add Reference...`, I can't seem to find ANY dependencies that I can use. Not under the `Assemblies` tab, nothing under `Assemblies` -> `Framework` or `Extensions`.

I'm just trying to grasp how this actually works, and how come I can't find any dependencies?

Comment: I'm, using dynamic with .net standard 1.6 libraries without any extra reference...

Comment: What version of the Visual Studio and/or C# compiler are you using?

Comment: @EugeneKomisarenko It's VS 2017, how can I find compiler version?

Comment: @Hans Passant The problem is easily reproducible with VS 2017 and NETStandard Class Library 1.6. The dynamic type in the body of the method is compiling well, but once you use it as a property type you get the same compilation error. See answer below of how to fix it.

Comment: Ah, .NETStandard, not .NETCore.  Sorry for messing with your answer.

Comment: @Hans Passant, thank you for your edit!

Comment: On second thought, there is something fishy about it.  Since you add a nuget package, the class library no longer conforms with the selected .NETStandard.  So can't run on all possible targets that the selected .NETStandard promises.  Hmm.

Answer (score 6):

Right-click the Dependencies node of your project > Manage Nuget Packages > Browse and type "dynamic" in the search box.  Pick [`System.Dynamic.Runtime`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Dynamic.Runtime/) from the top of the list, now you can use `dynamic` in your source code.

---

If you were like me interested in the reason of why you can use `dynamic` keyword without referencing DLR libraries in the code of the method, but cannot in the declarations of the properties, keep reading.

Have a look at the following lines of C# code below which are compiling with no issue using NETStandard.Library without referencing `System.Dynamic.Runtime`. The main difference between Line 1 and Line 3 in the C# code below is the usage of the keyword [dynamic vs var](https://stackoverflow.com/a/961594/920557) or dynamic vs static typing.

```
Line 1: dynamic a = new {a = 1, b = 2};
Line 2: a = new Class1();
Line 3: var b = new { a = 1, b = 2 };
```

And here is the simplified IL of the same three lines for your reference.

```
Line 1: newobj     instance void class '<>f__AnonymousType0`2'<int32,int32>::.ctor(!0,!1)
Line 2: newobj     instance void ClassLibrary2.Class1::.ctor()
Line 3: newobj     instance void class '<>f__AnonymousType0`2'<int32,int32>::.ctor(!0,!1)
```

If you compare Line 1 and Line 3 of the resulting IL code you will find no difference at all. The compiler can infer the [type of the variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) from the initialization code as well as enable re-initialization of the same variable for different types. No dependency on DLR required in this scenario.

On the other hand, something completely different is taking place when you declare the auto property of the class as `dynamic`.

```
public class Class1 { public dynamic Test { get; set; } }
```

The IL code of the auto-property reveals `dynamic` property being converted to a private backing field of the type `object` as well as the code of the initialization, getter, and setter which is heavily relying on the [`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.dynamicattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) from `System.Dynamic.Runtime` bringing in the dependency to DLR in this case.

Comment: Very neat answer, however at the time I wrote this SO, I couldn't find anything in the NuGet manager. Not even the dynamic. Perhaps I should check again? Will do later today.

Comment: Make sure you switch to Browse tab in NuGet not Installed or Updates... it is sometimes confusing.