# Accessing property of generic class from non-generic base class

Tags: c#, generics

I have classes/interfaces similar to the following:

```
    public interface IValueToken
    {
    }

    public abstract class ProgramToken
    {
        public ProgramToken(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; }
    }


    public class ValueToken<T> : ProgramToken, IValueToken
    {
        public ValueToken(string name, T value) : base(name)
        {
            Item = value;
        }

        T Item { get; }
    }
```

There are different generic `ValueToken<T>` types and they are held in a `List<ProgramToken>`, along with other types derived from `ProgramToken`

I need to do similar to this:

```
            var token = new ValueToken<int>("int", 78);

            if (token is IValueToken ivt)
            {
                var value = ivt.Value;
                // do something with value
                ....
            }
```

Some posts here at SO mentioned doing similar to how List does it, implementing the non-generic interface explicitly. I thought it was something like this:

Change `IValueToken` to

```
    public interface IValueToken
    {
        object Item { get; }
    }
```

and ValueToken to

```
    public class ValueToken<T> : ProgramToken, IValueToken
    {
        public ValueToken(string name, T value) : base(name)
        {
            Item = value;
        }

        object IValueToken.Item { get { return (T)Item; } }

        T Item { get; }
    }
```

But this isn't working the same as `List<T>`. It returns an `object` type.
What am I doing wrong? Or what is a better way of accomplishing this?

Comment: "It returns an object type." What type did you expect it to return? Also, your list is a list of `ProgramToken`s, which does not necessarily contain `IValueToken`s. Did you mean to have a list of `IValueToken`s instead?

Comment: What is `// do something with value` actually going to be?

Comment: Side note: you may want to carefully read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961581/whats-the-difference-between-dynamic-c-4-and-var

Comment: @Sweeper No the list contains other types derived from 'ProgramToken'.

Comment: @Charlieface In the actual implementation it's only important to get the value. At the places the value is required it just needs to be retrieved. eg, `T` could be int or could be double. Both can be added to a `List<double>` without explicitly casting

Comment: If you declare a property as type `object` then how could it possibly return anything other than an `object` reference? Casting `Item` as `T` in the `IValueToken.Item` getter is pointless. `Item` is already type `T` so the cast does nothing and `IValueToken.Item` is type `object` so any object will be returned as a reference of type `object`, no matter what.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes I realize that now. I've tried so many ways to do this and am totally confused. Is this not possible then? Do I really have to stick to type-checking every type T could be and casting to that type to access the Value property?

Comment: Well one option would be adding a `public double CastedValue { get; }` to the interface, then each generic type will have to find a way of implementing it, either by casting or parsing.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you've said in comments, you just need it to return a `double`.

In .NET 7 you can do this by constraining to `INumberBase<T>`

```cs
public class ValueToken<T> : ProgramToken, IValueToken
    where T : INumberBase<T>
{
    public ValueToken(string name, T value) : base(name)
    {
        Item = value;
    }

    double IValueToken.Item => double.CreateChecked(Item);

    T Item { get; }
}
```

In older versions you would have to have a derived class `IntToken : ValueToke<int>` which knows how to do the conversion.

Comment: Yes this would be great if I was only concerned with basic numeric types. Unfortunately that's not the case. Is there any way of maybe creating a conversion class/wrapper that would return the Value no matter what it's type, and without reflection? Everything I've tried requires supplying the generic types. If that's what I'm stuck with then I may as well ditch the generics and do pattern matching everywhere.

Comment: Well how do you propose to convert any random `RandomClass` into the one you want? Unless you have a way of defining such a conversion then it can't be done.