# Django: SQL way (i.e using annotation, aggregate, subquery, when, case, window etc) vs python way

Tags: django

Sql way means using using annotation, aggregate, subquery, when, case, window etc. i.e get all the extra calculation columns from sql

Till now if I want to get some addition information from the data of each row like calculate something etc, I used to get the table in queryset and loop over each object and then store the desired result in a list of dicts and pass it to the template. Ofcourse i was using prefetch so that i can avoid N+1 queries.

But since django 1.11 we can do the same thing in more expressive way using sql (i.e using annotation, aggregate, subquery, when, case, window etc)  and no python.

> Disadvantage:

One disadvantage i found using sql way rather than python way is debugging.

I have to do complex calculations on the data of each queryset object. So that i can check step by step.

If i do it in the sql way i can only see the final result but not be able to track the steps.

> Advantage:

I didnt tried, but heard from [The Dramatic Benefits of Django Subqueries and Annotations](https://medium.com/@hansonkd/the-dramatic-benefits-of-django-subqueries-and-annotations-4195e0dafb16) that its quite fast.

Presently most of my sql takes less than 100 ms and most of the time goes in dom loading. So by using sql way will it help me any way.

I appreciate that Django created more functions which help to write the sql expressively.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using an ORM or plain SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494816/using-an-orm-or-plain-sql)

Comment: ok i will try as per that answer. it says for reporting large data use sql and for create, update and delete use orm.

Comment: Also i want know will dom content loading time change if i use sql way

Comment: my 2 cents: if it's a critical path and you're not sure, profile it.