# Java EE Data layer frameworks

Tags: jakarta-ee, frameworks, data-layers

I am trying to figure out what are the most widely used frameworks on the data layer on a Java EE application server.

I would like help in knowing which are used out there and what are their Pros and Cons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) (as ORM tool) or Java EE JPA standardized API of EJB3, [iBATIS](http://ibatis.apache.org/) (as Data Mapper Tool), or more or less raw JDBC. For more details, see previous questions like [Using an ORM or plain SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494816/using-an-orm-or-plain-sql/494853#494853) or [Hibernate, iBatis, Java EE or other Java ORM tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716532/hibernate-ibatis-java-ee-or-other-java-orm-tool).