# Implementing database access using Spring or separate library / pattern?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, spring-jdbc

I'm working on an app which uses hard coded sql statements to retrieve data from a database and then populate this data into pojo's. Spring jdbc template is being used so dont need to worry about opening/closing connections. Using hard-coded sql statements seems wrong ?

Is there a design pattern or library I can use to abstact the sql statements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing inherently wrong with having SQL inside Java classes (although it's a bit controversial). If you want to externalize SQL queries you can:

- use [MyBatis](http://blog.mybatis.org/) which is very mature
- put SQL in your `applicationContext.xml` Spring configuration file and inject it to POJOs (poor man's MyBatis)
- hide SQL behind DAO pattern (`interface SomeDao` and `class SqlSomeDao` having SQL encapsulated)
- ...going for full ORM like JPA if you already have SQLs is not the best idea

<sup>Also check out [Spring Data JDBC generic DAO](https://github.com/nurkiewicz/spring-data-jdbc-repository) - small DAO implementation on top of `JdbcTemplate` and `RowMapper<T>`. Disclaimer: I'm an author of this library.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Look at [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org) (formly iBatis).

- It let's you extract hardcoded SQLs into XML files (or even annotations),
- It integrates with Spring container, and can use Spring Transaction.

and many more.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good previous discussion of some of the issues surrounding the choice between using raw SQL or an ORM tool:

[Hibernate, iBatis, Java EE or other Java ORM tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716532/hibernate-ibatis-java-ee-or-other-java-orm-tool)

Answer (score 1):

Using `JdbcTemplate`, your application code still has the responsibility to provide `sql` and the `JdbcTemplate` can then execute SQL query or updates, iterate over ResultSets and catch JDBC exceptions. If you want to get away with writing hard-coded sql statements, you need to look into an ORM tools like `Hibernate`, `iBatis`etc