# How to get superior terror checking of MySQL queries

Tags: java, mysql, orm, jdbc

I just started using MySQL and I just can see myself woking with strings!
I mean the compiler can't catch errors like this and it's just a mess!
Is there a wrapper or some kind of class I can add that does something as simple as making a function that adds a table and asks for args?

I'm sure there is a tool like that but I can't find it or know its name.

Comment: Yes, working with SQL queries **is** working with the strings. Very handy. What'd wrong for you in this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're basically looking for an Object Relational Mapper. [Hibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/) is one of the pioniers in this area. [JPA](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbpy.html) is a new and well-established Java EE standard in this area, formed by the guy behind Hibernate. Hibernate and [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) offers JPA implementations.

There exist IDE tools to autogenerate Java classes based on database models and vice versa, such as [Hibernate Tools](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.0.0.CR1/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html) for "good old" Hibernate and [Eclipse Dali](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/tutorial_1.0/dali_jsf_tutorial.htm) for JPA.

If you don't want to use an ORM and/or don't want to autogenerate model objects, then you just have to make sure that you design the right model objects for the database model. I.e. use a `Long` property for a `BIGINT` field, a `BigDecimal` property for a `DECIMAL` field, etcetera. You can find an overview of the default mappings in [this page](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/spec/jdbc-spec.frame8.html).

In "plain vanilla" JDBC you should at least use [`PreparedStatement`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) methods to compose the SQL query rather than concatenating as String. There are a lot of `setXXX()` methods for the specific datatype, such as `setLong()`, `setBigDecimal()`, etcetera. The `PreparedStatement` not only eases setting fullworthy Java objects like `Date` and `InputStream` in a SQL query, but it also prevents the code from [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) [attacks](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html). You can learn more about `PreparedStatement` in the [Sun JDBC tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and you can find a basic kickoff DAO tutorial in [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html).

Comment: tnx ill start looking at all this

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object-relational mapper like [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/).  See also [What Java ORM do you prefer, and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452385/what-java-orm-do-you-prefer-and-why).

Answer (score 1):

Give JDBC [prepared statements](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) a try.

Comment: "Dummies" in question title and spelling suggests just that.