# Database handlers for Servlets

Tags: java, database, jsp

I'm about to start developing a dynamic web application with Java (i.e., Servlets and JSP).
Obviously I will need to keep a database with all sorts of information (Users, etc.). My question is - is there a good library for saving/storing/retrieving from a database for this kind of application?
I don't mean JDBC, which is used to send queries and parse results, but some sort of abstraction for saving and loading my object to/from the database.

Currently, I am trying to develop some sort of generic classes for handling of these cases in django style (i.e., classes have a `save()` method), but since these are generic, I suppose something ought to exist already.

Comment: ORM solution like Hibernate or iBatis?

Comment: Also look at: [What Java ORM do you prefer, and why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452385/what-java-orm-do-you-prefer-and-why)

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are looking for an Object Relational Mapping (ORM) tool.  ORMs map rows in a table to objects in your code.  In fact, what you have been using in Django is an ORM.

[Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) is one such ORM that will let you describe how your Java objects should be mapped.