# Lightweight JDBC helper library alternative to Apache Commons DbUtils

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-commons, helper

I've just developed my own tiny little JDBC helper library, and I've already realized what a maintenance nightmare it will be.

I'm not looking for a full fledged ORM, like Hibernate, just something light and useful to quickly make JDBC calls passing SQL statements without messing with checked exceptions, closing resources manually, etc...

From your experiencie, can you recommend a nice JDBC helper library?

So far now, I've had a look at [Apache Commons DbUtils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/examples.html) which seems pretty good. Any other idea?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here's a list of tools that "ease the pain" when interacting with simple JDBC:

- Spring's [JdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#jdbc-core)
- [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) (can be used with SQL strings as well - disclaimer: I work for the vendor)
- [Apache DbUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/) (which you've mentioned yourself)
- [JDBI](http://jdbi.org/)
- [sql2o](http://www.sql2o.org/)
- [persism](http://persism.sourceforge.net/main.php)

Comment: JDBC is really awesome, I think the should externalize it from Spring Framwork

Comment: @deFreitas: Why? It's just a single class and you could write it yourself in 10-20 minutes...

Comment: Because I don't think that re-write JDCTemplate and PlatformTransactionManager with a good code quality and all it core features will take just 20 minutes and because I don't see why re-write something that works really well and it's maintained by all community

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The essence of JdbcTemplate is just syntax sugar over JDBC APIs. But OK fine, if you don't want to roll your own, just copy paste the one from Spring. It's ASL 2.0 licensed, so you're quite free to do with it whatever you want, removing the Spring dependency. But anyway, you probably meant something else.

Comment: Is it me or the list order has a meaning? I guess it's popularity ;-)

Comment: @sajjadG The first two are alphabetical. The rest are random.

Answer (score 6):

There's also [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) and [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org) which are pretty lightweight as well.  Using spring and it's rowmappers is pretty easy, but does require you to deal directly with the JDBC.  Something like either of the above will hide alot of that away from you, while not being as overly complicated as hibernate.

Answer (score 5):

https://code.google.com/p/jdbc-helper/

Here is the description I copied from its project page: 
*Inspired by Spring Jdbctemplate and Commons Dbutils projects, JdbcHelper is a very small library for helping the developers code common jdbc operations. JdbcHelper is very lightweight. It is only ~70K and it has no external dependencies.*

Answer (score 4):

There is [Yank](https://github.com/timmolter/Yank), which is an ultra-light JDBC persistance layer that wraps DBUtils. To use it you create for each table a POJO and a DAO Class. You write your own SQL statements and execute queries through the DBProxy class. You don't have to  deal with Connections, ResultSets, and or other low level JDBC code. The Yank jar is only 13 KB as of release 2.0.0, and it depends on only SLF4J, DBUtils, and a 3rd-party database jar, whichever database technology you're using.

Comment: All I had to see was "BooksDAO.selectAllBooks()" to know that this can't work well.   Its effectively what I built 6 years ago and makes all the mistakes I did.  It should be "new BooksDAO(transaction).selectAllBooks()".  Transaction demarcation and context must not be entangled with queries, and should not be handled via static means or else testability and debugability will suffer.

Comment: "... this can't work well" is quite an unfair statement. It does in fact work perfectly well if you do not need to execute multiple statements per transaction. Yank never claims to support multi-statement transactions.

Comment: i have see the Yank source code, i don't think it is a good practice.  i have write a simple DbUtils help. http://a123159521.iteye.com/blog/2200647

Comment: @herrtim I do not think the statement is unfair.  Even if you do not want to support multiple statements in a transaction, the static cling will kill you.  You can not write any code that depends on BooksDAO without statically binding it to the database and a concrete implementation.  I stand by `SomeDAO.someStaticMethod()` == bad practice.  `someDAOImplementation.someInstanceMethod()` is vastly superior.

Comment: Don't waste your time with Yank, it's a pain in the ... you will spend hours with untraceable errors. Finally, this driver can't perform updates and have serious problems translating SQL text commands.

Answer (score 1):

[Spring Framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) (spring-dao) is your friend. If you program your interfaces correctly, later (provided it would be necessary) you can easily switch to something more powerful like Hibernate. Also don't underestimate Hibernate: [Native SQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html) gives you a power of full SQL and still you can benefit from object mapping – something which you will have to program anyway unless you only need to execute the queries as simple as `select count(*) from ...`.

Answer (score 1):

In cases where an ORM is not neccessary I use springs [JdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#jdbc-core) .

Examples

- http://www.theserverside.com/tip/Database-Access-with-Spring-30-and-the-JdbcTemplate
- http://www.vogella.de/articles/SpringJDBC/article.html