# JDBC connectivity persistence issue

Tags: java, database, swing, jdbc

I understand that jdbc involved these steps

- Import the packages,
- Register the JDBC driver,
- Open a connection,
- Execute a query,
- Extract data from result set,
- Clean up the environment.

I have 2 java files one is for GUI (Swing) and another is normal Java file. I have many input fields in GUI and send them to backend file for processing using JDBC.  I have many methods like this in my Java file.  The problem is in each method I have to the entire steps (mentioned above) in each of these methods. As a result of this it has become slow. I wanted to optimize it making first 3 steps and final steps mentioned above only once.

How  to achieve this?

Comment: You do not have to increase it, but you might find people are more willing to answer when there is a chance their answer gets accepted. And it is nice if you can immediately see whether an answer solved the problem or not. The link @AndrewThompson provided contains more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need a `Connection Pool`.  There are lots of questions related to connection pooling on Stack Overflow - there's even a tag for it!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connection-pooling

Comment: Does the connection pool works if i have multiple gui frames(in case of swings). i mean can i create that connection only once for all the requests from multiple gui frames..which connection pool is suitable in this case..can u give a link which has this kind of example..

Comment: The connection pool doesn't care about GUIs; it only cares about your connections to a database.  In your 'Java file', set up the connection pool when the application starts and close it when the application is closed.  Then you can access it whenever you need to.  If you have a specific question, I would recommend creating a new Question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

In broad outline, here are several approaches, in (roughly) increasing order of complexity:

- Stick with what you're doing, abstracting useful utilities as you learn. It's laborious, but  it allows maximal cutomization.
- Adopt a lightweight JDBC helper library; several are cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7137929/230513).
- Dive in and learn the [Java Persistence API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html).

It's entirely possible to do the first while exploring the second or third.