# How to design JDBC access in Java library?

Tags: java, jdbc

We at point to implement library which hide common business logic across many applications.

Library require access to DB.

Which design decision we must take in account to do job the best (in order to reduce long term support cost)?

Previously I use Spring `SimpleJdbcTemplate` and `plain JDBC` code only and want to get simplicity as in `SimpleJdbcTemplate` without dependency of huge framework and to avoid version conflicts on external libraries (recall - we say about library, not application).

Comment: Don't yet try but for info this look promising:  http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/

Comment: Another promising library http://www.sormula.org/ but with GPL 2.0 license restriction...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137929/lightweight-jdbc-helper-library-alternative-to-apache-commons-dbutils

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending several hours I found nice projects:

- http://jdbi.org/ - most impressive
- http://www.jooq.org/
- http://www.sql2o.org/

Answer (score 2):

1. use connection pool. Any server application, connection pooling is very efficient to reduce connect/disconnect db. dbcp or # of connection pooling can be considered.
2. separate read/write connection.
   If you are considering to scale out, i'd like to recommend separate read & write db connection.  Commonly RDBMS support read replica. So for write connection, it just can be used for db write/update/delete and read connection can be used for read transaction only. As u can imagine, % of read transaction is usually 70~90% (depends on application type)
3. Before thinking about Spring JDBC or pure JDBC etc. You'd better to think about pure SQL coding or OR-Mapping (JPA, Hibernate, Mybatis etc). 
   There are pros & cons depends on the framework.

Comment: Thnks for answer! ORM have disadvantage in dependency on bloat frameworks. It is hard to force users to use any framework you like....

Comment: If u feel burden in ORM framework. What about MyBatis. It is very simple and lightweight. And it is very simillar to SpringJDBCTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

I would use spring-jdbc for database interaction. Libraries may have dependencies. Use Maven and there will be no versioning problem. Spring-jdbc is not huge.

Comment: Spring-jdbc require: `spring-core`, `spring-beans`, `spring-tx`, `spring-asm`. I afraid that application that uses library have some problem with Spring versions. For example if application uses Spring 2.0 and our library Spring 4.0 - what happen?

Comment: People who use the library will tune their project's pom.

Comment: as  Evgeniy mentioned, through your pom you can include project specific dependency. >>>>> Generally I prefer using same spring version dependency. >>>>> In case you need different API's which have dependency on different spring version you would need to have specific dependencies added as OSGi bundle. Thus allowing individual core dependency jars to be loaded separately and use only their dependencies at their runtime. >>>>> Also frankly speaking if you are choosing set of libraries with different version, you already increase complexity