# When to close SQL Connection with DAO pattern?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am building a `REST` service that contains code that looks something like this:

```
@PUT
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response updateOrder(        
        @HeaderParam("user") String user
        ){

    CoffeeOrderDAO coffeeDAO = new CoffeeOrderDAOImpl();

    ....

    coffeeDAO.method1();

    ....

    coffeeDAO.method2();

    ....
```

`CoffeeOrderDAOImpl`

```
public class CoffeeOrderDAOImpl implements CoffeeOrderDAO{

Context ctx;
DataSource ds;
Connection conn;

public CoffeeOrderDAOImpl(){

    try {
        ctx = new InitialContext();
        ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/coffeeDB");
        conn = ds.getConnection();

    } catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Exception:" + e);                           
    } catch (NamingException ne) {

    }
}

public String method1() {

}

public String method2() {

}
```

My question is should I be closing the connection in BOTH `method1()` AND `method2()` and create a new `CoffeeOrderDAO` object before calling these two methods?

OR

Use the same `CoffeeOrderDAO` object for both methods and only close the connection in `method2()`

The second option seems odd in that it becomes more complicated to know when connections were closed.

So is it proper to create multiple `CoffeeOrderDAO` objects or am I missing something?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: How about moving the connection out of the DAO, have a Factory for the connection

Comment: Instead of direct connection use connection pooling.

Comment: Google for `java entitymanagerhelper`

Comment: The connection might be closed by the DBMS so it's a bad idea to have a field for that, open it on object init., and assume it's ready to use

Answer (score 1):

If anything, you should at least be using some abstraction over JDBC. You shouldn't be handling the intricacies of connections on your own.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18672009/2504224) SO answer for a suggestion of such tools. Those tools do all the heavy lifting for you.

Besides making your code a lot less error prone, using one of these tools will make the code a lot more readable since it will contain a lot less boilerplate code