# Database access class best practices

Tags: java, database

Im creating a simple DBHelper for my postgre DB using a JDBC driver.

Im wondering what are the best practices?

For example, are methods like `initConnection() closeConnection()` or any other, should be static one? Like:

```
void foo{
    DBHelper.initConnection();
    // do some logic, maybe:
    // Data someData = DBHelper.getSomeData();
    DBHelper.closeConnection();
}
```

Or maybe better if i will create a DBHelper object and call method for object. Like:

```
void foo2{
    DBHelper dbhelper = new DBHelper();
    dbhelper.initConnection();
    // do some logic, maybe:
    // Data someData = dbhelper.getSomeData();
    dbhelper.closeConnection();
}
```

Is it matter at all?

Do i need always check if connection is open before i will try to retrive some data? What if it is close? And always try to close it in `finally` block?

EDIT:
in answer to @Kayaman comment:

So my foo method like this?

```
 void foo3{
    Connection conn = DBHelper.getConnection();
    // do some logic, maybe:
    // Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
    // some stmt work
    conn.close() //do i need check if stmt is closed before? 
}
```

That will make my DBHelper class usefull only to getting connection. There will be no logic inside? (like `GetInterestingRecords()` or `GetRecordsWithId(30)` ?

Comment: Well, this is a broad question, but I'd recommend a `getConnection()` method that returns a new `Connection` every time, and you just calling `con.close();` in the code that uses the connection after you're done with it.

Comment: @Kayaman if u can check my edited question. Ty for response anyway! :)

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to create `getRecordsWithId(int)`. It makes more sense to create DAO classes with methods like `getUserById(int), getUserByLastName(String)` etc. Business logic shouldn't go to a helper class.

Comment: @Kayaman okey it is clear enough for me. How about static/nonstatic problem? is code i wrote above correct? Or should i create an object? or maybe doesnt matter ?

Comment: It depends on whether you intend to keep state in there, but you'll probably be fine with a static method.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about defining the connection properties in the server config file (if it is a web app) and have the session opened for the whole application lifecycle?

Comment: yeah, i have already done smth like this in my other project, however this is not a web app

Comment: but this idea is completely different compared to @Keyaman one, he suggest to open connection before and close after every interaction with DB

Comment: Yes, the idea behind is that a client has connectio  to the database for the application lifecycle and not on demand.

Answer (score 1):

Before implementing DBHelper you should check if some java libraries may satisfy your needs. If you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137929/lightweight-jdbc-helper-library-alternative-to-apache-commons-dbutils) there are listed some libraries that seem to fit your problem.

If you decide to go on with your own custom implementation I suggest to make DBHelper a normal class with no static methods for managing the connections; the main reason is that with static methods you cannot manage multiple (i.e. connections to different databases) db connections at the same time. If you are using a java 7 implementation in your onw library you could also implement tha `AutoClosable` inferface in order to better manage the resource you library is managing.

Comment: any other pros or cons of static/nonstatic?

Comment: some basic jdbc utils such as close(connection), close(resultSet) may be static but the other ones that encapsulate an Object and wrap it (as DBHelper withc datasource) are better designed as nonstatic