# Tomcat8 + c3p0, connections are being interruped and auto closed

Tags: java, maven, c3p0, tomcat8

I'm developing a web app on Tomcat 8 with Maven, I'm using c3p0 to handle connections on the main thread and on 2 other concurrent threads, my connection manager class is asking a DataSource singleton class I've implemented for synchronized connections, like so

```
public synchronized Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        return cpds.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        logger.error("Error while issuing a pooled connection", ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

, but when I'm trying to use these connections they start to either interrupt

```
09:47:17.164 [QuartzScheduler_Worker-4] ERROR com.myapp.providers.DataSource - Error while issuing a pooled connection
java.sql.SQLException: An SQLException was provoked by the following failure: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106) ~[c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:0.9.1.2]
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:65) ~[c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:0.9.1.2]
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:62) ~[c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:0.9.1.2]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:531) ~[c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:0.9.1.2]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128) ~[c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:0.9.1.2]
```

or close in mid transaction and breaking any statements and result sets that are being used at that time

I'm configuring the DataSource object like so

```
cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        cpds.setDriverClass(oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver);
        cpds.setJdbcUrl(jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521:XE);
        cpds.setUser("username");
        cpds.setPassword("password");

        // database connection properties
        cpds.setInitialPoolSize(10);
        cpds.setAcquireIncrement(3);
        cpds.setMaxPoolSize(100);
        cpds.setMinPoolSize(15);
        cpds.setMaxStatements(75);

        // connection pool preferences
        cpds.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(60);
        cpds.setMaxIdleTime(30000);
        cpds.setAutoCommitOnClose(false);
        cpds.setPreferredTestQuery("SELECT 1 FROM DUAL");
        cpds.setTestConnectionOnCheckin(false);
        cpds.setTestConnectionOnCheckout(false);
        cpds.setAcquireRetryAttempts(30);
        cpds.setAcquireRetryDelay(1000);
        cpds.setBreakAfterAcquireFailure(false);
```

I've also written a small test method that runs in a loop and queries the database for n times but that works fine.

Comment: Where is your crp0 config?

Comment: i'm configuring it programmatically, i'll edit it in in a sec

Comment: well in the @Steve Waldman 's answer , he points to a thread which has been hanged , so are you using different threads to open the connection and  use the connection ? If you are using the connection in a thread , which is not context aware(meaning that tomcat does not know its existence) when another thread asks for a connection from the pool , tomcat aggressively is interrupting the first thread to pass the connection the second thread

Comment: If this is a new project, I would suggest you forgo such manual labour. There is no need to open/close connections on your own. There are plenty of projects that will do this plumbing for you. Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137929/lightweight-jdbc-helper-library-alternative-to-apache-commons-dbutils). Using any of these projects, what you do is setup the `DataSource` and pass is to some specific class that can then be used to perform the database operations. Also, I would not use c3p0, but instead I would opt for [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP)

Comment: it's not a new project, I also don't do all the work on those 2 threads. in some cases I open a connection in an Jersey2 endpoint (i.e. to return a GET response)

Comment: jersey's endpoint is a context aware thread because behind the scenes it is the actual servlet . If you are calling explicitly new Thread().start() inside the endpoint , then this thread is not context aware , so if the pool is exhausted , tomcat will aggressively unbind the connection from the thread because in reality he cannot understand at the time that it is being used. i would suggest you to use an ExecutorThreadPool(you can extend / customize it) which will be bind on the server , so all the threads inside the pool will be context aware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c3p0-0.9.1.2 is very, very old; please consider upgrading to 0.9.5.1, the current production version.

The problem is both clear and not so clear. The clear part is that something is calling `interrupt()` on client Threads that are waiting to acquire Connections. The not-so-clear part is who is doing that and why.

A guess is that Tomcat itself is doing that because the client Threads are hung too long. If the Threads are hanging at `getConnection()`, that could be due to a Connection leak and pool exhaustion. We see above how you acquire Connections. Are you vigilant about ensuring that they are reliably `close()`ed in finally blocks?

A thing you might try is to set a [checkoutTimeout](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#checkoutTimeout), e.g.

```
cpds.setCheckoutTimeout( 5000 ); // 5 secs
```

This won't actually solve the problem if Connection checkouts are hanging. But rather than a problem provoked by mysterious interrupts, you'll see c3p0 TimeoutExceptions instead. That will verify that the issue is long hangs on checkout, though, which would most likely be due to pool exhaustion, either from a Connection leak (missing calls to `close()`), or simply from a `maxPoolSize` value too low for your load.

If there does seem to be a Connection leak, please see [unreturnedConnectionTimeout](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#unreturnedConnectionTimeout) and [debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces) for help tracking it down. See also ["Configuring to Debug and Workaround Broken Client Applications"](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients)

Comment: I've noticed the older version and upgraded. the issue stayed. taking your advice, I've set setCheckoutTimeout(500) and got : java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
exception. The pool is exhausted very quickly, I guessed that might be the problem.

Comment: (i'd try 5000 rather than 500 msecs. usually Connections should check out within 500 msecs, but if the pool if the pool is temporarily exhausted, because it needs to expand or because other clients are using Connections but will soon return them, it's conceivable you might see that kind of delay occasionally. i suspect it won't make much of a difference though, and you'll still see the timeouts.)

Comment: (`unreturnedConnectionTimeout` and `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces` are very, very helpful for finding Connection leaks.)

Comment: set to 5000 and nothing, added `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` and `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces`, i'm only getting `InterruptedException`'s

Comment: to what did you set `unreturnedConnectionTimeout`?

Comment: 1000, probably should have set it higher

Comment: `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` is in seconds, not milliseconds, so you probably want a much smaller value than 1000 (unless your app runs very slow queries, something between 2 to 5 secs should be plenty).