# Formatting data from a result set with the toString() method

Tags: java, jdbc

My question is this, what is the most efficient way to use the toString method to format data from a ResultSet?

Here is the method that I have thus far:

```
public void query()
{
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try
    {
        //Create database connection
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/registrar",
                "abt1s", "abt1s");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        //create SQL statement
        String st = "SELECT * FROM  student WHERE studentID = '" + this.getStudentID() + " '";

        rs = stmt.executeQuery(st);

        String studentData = rs.toString();
        System.out.println(studentData);

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.err.println("ERROR: Either cannot connect to the DB " + " or error with the SQL statement");
            }

}
```

Comment: What do you want to see on output?  Why do you believe this is not efficient enough for your uses?

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM  student WHERE studentID = '" + this.getStudentID() + " '";` is a potential [SQL injection risk](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java).  Please get in the habit of using prepared statements instead.

Comment: Your code leaves SQL connections open when a single statement fails with a `SQLException`.  Maybe put the close code in a `finally` block.

Comment: I understand about prepared statements. I will make that change. the code that I have returns the hash of the ResultSet. What I need to do is, print the data contained in the rs using the overridden toString method. That is not included in the example, but I think I have coded that correctly.

Comment: On what class is your `toString` method defined?  The implementation of `ResultSet` returned is determined by the JDBC driver, not your code, so you can pass it to a `static` method that turns it into a `String` but unless you are implementing your own `Driver` wrapper, you have little control over what `rs.toString` does.

Comment: I have defined the toString method in a class called Graduate. The query method that I submitted is also declared in this class. The entire project consists of three classes that all inherit from a Student class. I have overridden the toString method in each of these classes to suit there need. They also inherit the toString from the Student superclass

Comment: `toString()` is for debugging, not meeting system design criteria. Use a dedicated method, or at least dedicated code.

Answer (score 1):

You can go row by row through the ResultSet and print whatever you want:

```
// Fetch each row from the result set
while (rs.next()) {
    // Get the data from the row using the column index
    String s = rs.getString(1);

    // Get the data from the row using the column name
    s = rs.getString("col_string");
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and it does get the data from the result set. I will go back to using this. How would I format this using the toString method?

Comment: Because the ResultSet class is not your own class, you can't change it's methods. The best you could do is write a static method that takes in a ResultSet parameter and returns a string.

Comment: Basically, I'm supposed to implement the toString method to format the data and print to the screen. I'm just having a hard time seeing how that is done.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the `ResultSet` into a `Student` class before you can use `Student.toString` to generate the proper output.

["Retrieving and Modifying Values from Result Sets"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) explains one way of extracting data from a `ResultSet`.

Alternatively, you can look at an Object-Relational-Mapping (ORM) which eases creating domain objects (like `Student`) from database rows.  [What Java ORM do you prefer, and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452385/what-java-orm-do-you-prefer-and-why) has useful pointers to discussions of the various ORMs and how to get started with them.