# Writing SQL in Play with Scala?

Tags: sql, scala, orm, playframework

I'm looking at the documentation for the Play framework and it appears as though [SQL is being written in the framework](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/documentation/manual/scalaGuide/tutorials/todolist/ScalaTodoList.md#persist-the-tasks-in-a-database).

Coming from Rails, I know this as a bad practice. Mainly because developers require the need to switch databases as they scale.

What are the practices in Play to allow for developers to implement conventions and to work with databases without having to hard code SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the feature/defects (depending on who you ask) of Play is the **there is no ORM**. (An ORM is an object-relational mapper/mapping; it is the part of Rails, Django, etc. that writes your SQL for you.)

- Pro-ORM: You don't have to write any SQL.

  - Ease-of-use: Some developers unused to SQL will find this easier.
  - Code resuse: Tables are usually based on your classes; there is less duplication of code.
  - Portability: ORMs try smooth over any differences between DMBS vendors.
- No-ORM: You get to write your own SQL, and not rely on unseen ORM (black)magic.

  - Performance: I work for a company which produces high-traffic web applications. With millions of visitors, you need to know *exactly* what queries you are running, and *exactly* what indicies you are using. Otherwise, the code that worked so well in dev will crash production.
  - Flexibility: ORMs often do not have the full range of expression that a domain-specific language like SQL does. Some more complex sub-selects and aggregation queries will be difficult/impossible to write with ORMs.
  - While you may think "developers require the need to switch databases as they scale", if you scale enough to change your DBMS, *changing query syntax will be the least of your scalability issues*. Often, the queries themselves will have to be rewritten to use **sharding**, etc., at which point the ORM is dead.

It is a tradeoff; one that in my experience has often favored no ORM.

See the [Anorm](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaAnorm) page for Play's justification of this decision:

> **You don’t need another DSL to access relational databases**
>
> SQL is already the best DSL for accessing relational databases. We don’t need to invent something new.
>
> ...

---

Play developers will typically write their own SQL (much the same way they will write in other languages, like HTML), use [Anorm](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaAnorm), and follow common SQL conventions.

If portability is a requirement, use only [ANSI SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92) (no vendor-specific featues). It is generally well supported.

---

EDIT: Or if you are really open-minded, you might have a look at NoSQL databases, like Mongo. They are inherently object-based, so object-oriented Ruby/Python/Scala can be used as the API naturally.

Comment: I could probably go on a lengthly blog rant on why SQL within code is bad. A very long rant. Then again, I have a deep history in Rails so I'm sure half of my points will be the tears of change. My fear is that SQL isn't a nice language. At least that's what you get from Rails developers. We can, fortunately, see the SQL queries running and refactor our code as needed. I cannot agree with the point of inventing a new DSL for play. A supporting case study is Laravel, a PHP framework, which uses other PHP frameworks to build upon the shoulders of giants.

Comment: With SQL added, it feels as though working with Play is further out of reach for web developers that have a Django, Laravel, or Rails background. Scala, as a new language to a ruby, python, or PHP developer, is uncomfortable, but we make the leap. We attempt to master it. We put our heart into it. With SQL popping up, it feels like a sucker punch; IMHO. Are there no ORMs for Play to allow web developers to become more productive?

Comment: @BenMorganIO, it sounds like Rails is a better fit for your needs than Play. AFAIK, there is nothing is Play-specific, but Scala can use Java code, so you may broaden your search (e.g. Hiberante, [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/)) You could look at [What Java ORM do you prefer, and why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452385/what-java-orm-do-you-prefer-and-why), though the top-voted answer is "None" :P

Comment: @BenMorganIO, if you are in the business of blog posts, you might be interested in Jeff Atwood's (co-founder of Stack Overflow) post: [Object-Relational Mapping is the Vietnam of Computer Science](http://blog.codinghorror.com/object-relational-mapping-is-the-vietnam-of-computer-science/).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Paul Draper's excellent answer, this post is meant to tell you about what Play developers usually do in practice.

**TL;DR: [use](https://github.com/playframework/play-slick) [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/)**

Play is less opinionated than Rails and gives the user many more choices for their data storage backend. Many people use Play as a web layer for very complex existing backend systems. Many people use Play with a NoSQL storage backend (e.g. MongoDB). Then there's also people using Play for traditional web-service-with-SQL applications. Generalizing a bit too much, one can recognize two people using Play with relational databases.

**"Traditional web developers"**
They are used to standard Java technologies or are part of an organization that uses them. The Java Persistence API and its implementations (Hibernate, EclipseLink, etc...) are their ORM. You can do so too. There are also appear to be [Scala ORMs](http://sorm-framework.org/), but I'm less familiar with those.

Note that Java/Scala ORMs are still different ORMs *in style* when compared to Rails' ActiveRecord. Ruby is a dynamic language that allows/promotes loads of monkey patching and `method_missing` stuff, so there is `MyObject.finder_that_I_didnt_necessarily_have_to_write_myself()`. This style of ORM is called the [active record pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern). This style is impossible to accomplish in pure Java and discouraged in Scala (as it violates type safety), so you have to get used to writing a more traditional style using service layers and data access objects.

**"Scala web developers"**
Many Scala people think that ORMs are [a bad abstraction for database access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch). They also agree that using raw SQL is a bad idea, and that an abstraction is still in order. Luckily Scala is an expressive compiled language, and people have found a way to abstract database access that does not rely on the *object oriented language* paradigm as ORMs do, but mostly on the *functional language* paradigm. This is quite a similar idea to the [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINQ) query language Microsoft has made for their .NET framework languages. The core idea is that you don't have an ORM to perform query magic, nor write queries in SQL, but write them in *Scala itself*. The advantages of this approach are twofold:

1. You get a more fine grained control over what your queries actually execute when compared to ORMs.
2. Queries are checked for validity by the Scala compiler, so you don't get runtime errors for invalid SQL you wrote yourself. If it is valid Scala, it is translated to a valid SQL statement for you.

Two major libraries exist for accomplishing this. The first is [Squeryl](http://squeryl.org/). The second is [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/). Slick appears to be the most popular one, and there are some examples floating around the web that show how you are supposed to make it work with Play. Also check out [this video](http://parleys.com/play/51c2e20de4b0d38b54f46243/) that serves as an introduction to Slick and which compares it to the ORM approach.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I wrote a [short summary of the state of database access in Scala](http://manuel.bernhardt.io/2014/02/04/a-quick-tour-of-relational-database-access-with-scala/) some months ago. I personally found that using Slick in combination with its plain SQL querying capabilities to be quite convenient.