# How can I map MySQL query results to Java objects?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, dropwizard

I am building a [Dropwizard](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.5/docs/) application where I want to easily map results from a MySQL database to java objects. I have seen this done before with an Object mapper, so I know it can be done, but unfortunately I can't remember where or how.

I created Immutable classes and I'd like to map the values to them. Here is an example Immutable:

```
@Value.Immutable
public interface Task {
    int getTaskId();
    int getCreatorId();
    String getTitle();
    String getDescription();
    int getCreatedAt();
}
```

This is my DAO so far:

```
public interface TasksDAO {
    @SqlQuery("select task_id, title, description, creator_id, created_at from tasks")
    Set<ImmutableTask> getAllTasks();

    @SqlQuery("select task_id, title, description, creator_id, created_at from tasks where id = :id")
        ImmutableTask getTaskById(@Bind("id") int id);
}
```

It works with simpler data types like `String` or `int`.

Comment: The keyword to search for is [`java ORM`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+ORM), where [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) means "Object-Relational Mapping". See e.g. [What Java ORM do you prefer, and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/452385/5221149)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, I created a simple mapper for my object. This is what the Mapper looks like:

```
public class TaskMapper implements ResultSetMapper<ImmutableTask> {
    public ImmutableTask map(int index, ResultSet r, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException {
        return ImmutableTask.builder()
                .taskId(r.getInt("task_id"))
                .creatorId(r.getInt("creator_id"))
                .title(r.getString("title"))
                .description(r.getString("description"))
                .createdAt(r.getTimestamp("created_at"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

*(The builder is because it's an Immutable, but it can be replaced with `new Task()` in other cases)*

I then updated my DAO with the mapper annotation to look like this:

```
public interface TasksDAO {
    @SqlQuery("select task_id, title, description, creator_id, created_at from tasks")
    @Mapper(TaskMapper.class)
    Set<ImmutableTask> getAllTasks();

    @SqlQuery("select task_id, title, description, creator_id, created_at from tasks where task_id = :id")
    @Mapper(TaskMapper.class)
    ImmutableTask getTaskById(@Bind("id") int id);
}
```